# Questions regarding VTOL and VMU inhibits

Tags: avionics, vtol

I have been working on a game which has futuristic VTOL-capable air and aerospace crafts.

A player recently wrote that the stall warning (tone and aural) and AoA (tone and visual) were distracting/annoying/unnecessary/spurious during VTOL takeoff and landing. Same with the "don't sink" EGPWS call-out.

EDIT so that the post is less opinion-based?:
How should these be inhibited for helicopter or VTOL operations without sacrificing safety? For example, if the IAS is less than 50 knots we can assume that they are not trying to fly or recover and therefore we can ignore the AoA information? Or similarly if the AoA is more than 45 degrees up or down? That coupled with the gear being down or flaps in landing position? I also have other air data, radar altimetry, etc that could be used.

The game is called [Rise: The Vieneo Province](https://www.risetvp.com) if you want to check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of stall and the associated AoA limits aren't meaningful for a VTOL aircraft in the way you've described.  Those systems are designed to prevent a pilot from accidentally stalling the wing; but during the vertical flight phase lift is not being generated by a wing but some sort of propulsion system. So stall warning would be meaningless and likely distracting.

It might be better to look at the alerts that exist for helicopter pilots. Things like low rotor RPM alerts could translate more directly to your scenario (although that depends on how far in the future you're thinking).

A system like EGPWS or [HTAWS](https://www.rotorandwing.com/2009/11/01/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-taws/), which is the helicopter variant, would be the best place to start for designing your alerts. There are [specific rules](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgTSO.nsf/0/4e324b446be11b2d8625752300762a36/$FILE/TSO-C194.pdf)for how those systems need to be designed if you want to really get into it.